# Default identity value of a key function

Tags: python

Often a function takes an optional argument that defaults to the identity function (the function that returns its argument, *not* [`id`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id)). A typical example is the `key` argument of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted).

In my case the `key` is a class field:

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, key=None):
        ...
        self.key = key
        ...

    def method(self, x):
        ...
        if self.key:
            x = self.key(x)
        ...
```

The problem with `X` is code ugliness - I have to check `self.key` every time I use it.

```py
class Y:
    def __init__(self, key=(lambda x:x)):
        ...
        self.key = key
        ...

    def method(self, x):
        ...
        x = self.key(x)
        ...
```

This is nice, but instances of `Y` cannot be pickled:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Y.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

The final version is

```py
class Z:
    def __init__(self, key=None):
        ...
        self._key = key
        ...

    def key(self, x):
        if self._key:
            return self._key(x)
        return x

    def method(self, x):
        ...
        x = self.key(x)
        ...
```

`Z` is the longest version, and the boilerplate code is ugly.
(it can be shortened using `return x if self._key is None else self._key(x)`, but *some* people - although not me - shun this idiom),

So, what is the pythonic way here?

**PS**. Exactly for this reason Lisp has the [`identity`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_identi.htm) function (and the compiler eliminates calls to it), so the lispy way is `Y`. I am tempted to define my own `identity` but it feels stupid to define a trivial function just for default values.

Comment: Isn't it also the case that most key functions can't be pickled, though? If pickling is a requirement, then taking a user-provided function in the constructor seems problematic.

Comment: The boilerplate code could be written as `return self._key(x) if self._key else x` which might be considered a bit less ugly, since it doesn't repeat the `return` keyword and doesn't have two branches with different indentation.

Comment: @kaya3: plenty of functions _can_ be pickled (`numpy.exp` &c)

Comment: @kaya3: yeah, I like this idiom too, but I hear some people avoid it. At any rate, is _that_ the _pythonic way_? `Z` + `return/if/else`?

Comment: The way I see it, there are two solutions; either make a pickle-able identity function (it takes two lines to declare a named function which returns its argument) or do it the current way (I would favour the `return ... if ... else ...` style considering the expressions are simple enough, but it's a matter of opinion).

Comment: I would simply define an identity function `def identity(x): return x`, and use it in place of the lambda function in class Y...

Comment: @RiccardoBucco: in _every_ file where I might possibly need it ? ;-)

Comment: @sds This might sound stupid, but you were trying to do exactly the same with the lambda function. It doesn't make much difference.

Comment: The identity function only needs to be defined in the same file as the class.

Comment: @kaya3 Exactly. Defining a lambda function or a normal function does not sound like more complicated to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define an identity function and use it as a default parameter:

```
def identity(x):
    return x

class Y:
    def __init__(self, key=identity):
        ...
        self.key = key
        ...

    def method(self, x):
        ...
        x = self.key(x)
        ...
```

This works just fine and objects of this type can be pickled.